# Why won't my spinner appear upon clicking login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, spinner

I would like to make my spinner appear upon the user clicking login.  I'm checking to see if `loading` is true in `login()` method.  If it is, make the spinner appear.  I've been struggling with this for hours, can't see what am I doing wrong.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import fire from '../../config/Fire';
import classes from './Login.css';
import Spinner from '../../UI/Spinner/Spinner';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            loading: false
        };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    login() { 
        fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u) => {
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

        this.setState({loading: true});

        if(this.state.loading) {
            return(
              <Spinner/>
            );
        }
    }

    signup(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u) => {
        }).then((u) => {
            console.log(u)
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div className={classes.Middle}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <h1>Email address</h1>
                    <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} type="email" name="email"
                           className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <h1>Password</h1>
                    <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} type="password" name="password"
                           className="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>

                <Link to={{
                    pathname: '/ChooseTruck'
                }}>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.login.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </Link>


                <button onClick={this.signup}>Signup</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what your problem is, you are trying to return the loader in the login function which is doable, but not with your current implementation. What I would suggest you do is to put the `<Spinner />` component into the return of the render and only show it when the state is loading.

Something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        this.state.loading ? <Spinner /> : <div> rest of your code </div>
    )
}
```

Here you are saying, if the state of loading is true, then render the spinner, otherwise show the rest of the page. This is a much better approach for what you are trying to accomplish.

You can also remove the peace of code from the login function that returns the `Spinner` component.

```
if(this.state.loading) {
        return(
          <Spinner/>
        );
    }
```

Hit me up if you have any questions.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: bro.... I LITERALLY just fixed it on my own exactly the same way you mentioned before even seeing your post. thanks :D

Comment: You are a beast then! Good job.

Answer (score 0):

login should be a non-render method which makes your login request, it happens on an event. Your loading spinner should go in the render method (or a function called by it).

```
login() { 
  this.setState({loading: true});

  fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then((u) => {
      console.log(u);
    })
    .catch(console.error)
    .then(() => this.setState({loading: false}))
}


render() {
    return (

        <div className={classes.Middle}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <h1>Email address</h1>
                <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} type="email" name="email"
                       className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <h1>Password</h1>
                <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} type="password" name="password"
                       className="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>

            <Link to={{
                pathname: '/ChooseTruck'
            }}>
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.login.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </Link>


            <button onClick={this.signup}>Signup</button>

            {this.state.loading && <Spinner/>}
        </div>
    );
}
```